# Fancybox sends form data to other php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe, fancybox

This is the original script of fancybox

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href : 'go.php',
            type : 'iframe',
            padding : 5
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I want to send the data from the following form to POST them to "go.php" page via fancybox iframe script
I want to open `"go.php"` in the same/current window via fancybox

```
<form name="fancy" action="go.php" method="POST">
    <input name="text1" type="text">
    <input name="text2" type="text">

    **<input type="button" value="Submit" id="fancybox-manual-b"/>
    **<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="fancybox-manual-b"/>
</form>
```

If I used `type="button"`, fancybox iframe works but POST don't send anything to go.php
If I used `type="submit"`, fancybox iframe doesn't work but POST sends the form data to go.php correctly

Comment: use ajax on button click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're clicking on a 'Submit' button, the browser doesn't know that you want to send your form.

Just use type="button" and change your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
        $.post('go.php', $(this).parent().serialize())
            .done(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'go.php',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: When I receive the POST data into "go.php" and I try to insert into DB, I found that it always inserting 2 rows (1st one is empty row and the 2nd one is the correct POST data)....How can I insert the 2nd row only?

Comment: Show me how are you receiving and saving you data in go.php

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO calculator (country) VALUES ('$_POST[country]')");   -----------------  Check the DB: http://postimg.org/image/ug8l7cz1v/