# Form Fancybox Click.Funktion -> .php

Tags: php, forms, fancybox

This is my original html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-script-type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="false" />
    <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#fancybox-mail").click(function() {
                 $.fancybox.open({
            href : 'kontakt.php',
            type : 'iframe',
            padding : 5
                });
            });             
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
            box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
            <form class="pure-form" name="fancy" action="kontakt.php" method="post">
                <p>Name: <input name="name" placeholder="Name" size="25"> E-Mail: <input name="email" placeholder="beispiel@beispiel.de" size="25"><br /></p>
                <textarea style="resize:none" name="comments" cols="65" rows="15"></textarea><br />
                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="fancybox-mail"<br />
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to send the data from the form to kontakt.php, but it doesn't work.
i want a frame box with the result from my kontact.php.

only the fancybox works but POST don't send anything to kontakt.php...
(without fancybox it works).

i try the result from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865640/fancybox-sends-form-data-to-other-php-page), but it doesn't help me.

Have anyone an idea?

thanks,

Comment: remove the `action="kontakt.php"` from the form tag and try

Comment: it doesn't help, the same problem.

Comment: having any error in console regarding jquery

Comment: how can i take the error, i use a synology and i learn php right now.

Comment: i think it is the same problem like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865640/fancybox-sends-form-data-to-other-php-page

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last line of your form with

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="fancybox-mail"/><br />
```

type must be submit instead button

Comment: i replace it, now the page reloaded it himself. no fancy box, no mail.

Comment: i put action="kontakt.php" back. Now i take a mail with the information but not a fancy box.